# Java interacting with window

Tags: java

I would love to ask which library or is there any way I can use java to interact with window such as being able to access drive C, drive D and other parts of the window as shown in the

[image: picture].

I want to make it in GUI form.

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps you can do with [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/start/)

Comment: do you mean https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html

Comment: [How to Use File Choosers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html)

Comment: @GAVD, thank you :) I will check it

Comment: @Scary Wombat, ahhh, yes...thank you, that is what I been looking for...I will check it

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you, that is what I'm looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JFileChooser -

> JFileChooser provides a simple mechanism for the user to choose a
>   file.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html